# How to make 'sox' recognize 'lame'?

Tags: osx, mp3, sox

I tried to build sox on MacOS with MP3 support.  A few months back; I forget the details, but it either would not build that way, or afterwards it failed to accept MP3.

So I tried what was in the instructions about pointing an environment variable to lame.  That didn't work either.  I need to concatenate thousands of 1-3 second files into 21 larger files and I would rather not have to first convert them to .wav

I have two versions of lame, a recent "standard" and a custom built for a particular application.